# How to use the dot notation to call a Cordova plugin?

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a project where I'm using `Ionic2` / `Cordova Plugins` / `Android`.

```
$ mkdir stackoverflow-question
$ cd stackoverflow-question
$ git clone https://github.com/napolev/stackoverflow-question.git .
$ npm install
$ ionic platform add android
$ ionic run android -l
```

This project works properly. It is basically a `Hello World` project. When you click the button on the screen you get the message `Hello, World` returned by a `Cordova` plugin.

My problem is that on the line `17`:

https://github.com/napolev/stackoverflow-question/blob/75ecff023a250e14752762582a078d038957c89a/src/pages/home/home.ts#L17

I wanna use:

`window.hello.greet(...)`

instead of

`window["hello"].greet(...)`

but when I use: `window.hello.greet(...)` I get the error:

```
Property 'hello' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

As you can see on the following image:

[image]

Any idea on how to use the dot notation to make use of a custom `Cordova` plugin?

**[EDIT 1]**

As per `@sebaferreras` suggestion on his comment I changed the code in the following way and it is working properly:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NavController } from "ionic-angular";

@Component( {
    selector: "page-home",
    templateUrl: "home.html",
})
export class HomePage {

    private window: any = window;
    private greet: string;

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
    ) {}

    private doGreet() {
        this.window.hello.greet("World", (message) => {
            this.greet = message;
        }, () => {
            this.greet = "[ERROR]";
        });
    }
}
```

but I would like to know:

1. is it a good practice to do: `private window: any = window;`
2. is there any other type more specific than `any` that I can use on the line above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that error is just Typescript complaining about knowing nothing of a `hello` property in the `window` object, you can cast the `window` object to `any` like this:

```
(<any>window).hello.greet(...)
```

**Edit**

If you want to avoid the cast to `any`, you could create your own class based on the `Window` class like this:

```
export interface IGreetingService {
    greet(): void; // Here you can add any function signature
}

export class CustomWindow extends Window {
    hello: IGreetingService;
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
(<any>CustomWindow).hello.greet(...)
```

Or

```
private window: CustomWindow = window; // The cast is being done here!
this.window.hello.greet(...)
```

Comment: thanks, it works. But I have two small questions: 1- is it a good practice to use: `private window: any = window;`?, 2- is there any other type more specific than `any` that I can use on the previous line?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Regarding 1., since `window` is a global object, it doesn't make too much sense to assign it to a property of the component (the casting would be better in that case if you only use the `hello` property in a single place). About 2., please check the update in the answer above :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use custom plugins in Ionic/Cordova like this:
Add following line at the top of your file:

```
declare var NameOfTheJsModule
```

You can find the name of the js-module in plugin.xml of the plugin under the name property:

```
<js-module src="www/inappbrowser.js" name="inappbrowser">
  ...
</js-module>
```

so in this case:

```
delcare var inappbrowser;
```

and to use it e.g.:

```
this.inappbrowser.show();
```